# Best way to declare an array in a long running thread in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, garbage-collection

I have a long running thread that executes the `test()` method for very long time. What is the best way (in terms of memory & performance) to declare and initialize the `data` array? What about if `data` is a one-dimensional array?

Choice #1

```
public void test() {
    double[][] data;    //declare only

    while (true) {
        //initialize data here every time.
        data = new double[99][9999];

        //do some procesing with data
    }
}
```

Choice #2

```
public void test() {

    double[][] data = new double[99][9999];

    while (true) {
        //reset everything in data
        for (double[] row: data)
            Arrays.fill(row, 0.0);

        //do some procesing with data
    }
}
```

Choice #3 - any suggestions?

As I think choice #2 is better in terms of memory. In the case of choice #1, in every iteration, it gets a new allocation on the heap and the previous allocation is eligible for garbage collection. However, when the previous allocation will be free that depends on the garbage collector (GC). Sometimes, long array allocation may not take place in the young generation. In that case, it will be in the memory for a while (until a full GC). Therefore, memory usages may increase as long as the thread is running. GC only clears the memory when it is needed (particularly from the old generation). Are these observations correct?

Comment: You are worrying about the memory allocation, but you have no problem with iterating over your two dimensional array to fill it with zeros...

Comment: @Murat, that's probably just for this example.

Comment: I am worried about both memory and performance. Actually, I have a set of 1-D and 2-D arrays (double, int, byte types). Of course, not actually that large. 2-D arrays are [500][32768] and 1-D arrays are [32768]. Which is better reuse/initialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

999x999999 is roughly 1.000 million doubles, at 8 bytes per double that's 8Gb per allocation. You definitely want to reuse such a large memory chunk instead of throwing it to the garbage collector on each run.

Comment: Is it till better to reuse if the array size is just 999 and one-dimensional?

Comment: Reuse should be better in any case but the only way to tell for sure is doing a benchmark. However, my question would be why do you need such a large piece of memory for data. Which only makes sense to me if you need random access to any of the 1.000 million double for your algorithm. And even if everything is kept in memory the cache will work much better if you have a sequential a data access pattern instead of a random data access pattern.